# jQuery find().filter() equivalent in Puppeteer

Tags: jquery, puppeteer

I have this code in jQuery:

```
$(iframe).find('input[type=text]').filter(':visible:first').val("abc");
```

I tried to do it in Puppeteer like this:

```
const iframe = await page.frames().find(f => f.name() === 'iframe');
var inputText = await iframe.$('input[type=text]').filter(':visible:first');
await inputText.focus();
await page.keyboard.type("abc");
```

I got the following error:

```
iframe.$(...).filter is not a function
```

I also tried with iframe.$$ but got the same results.

**UPDATE:**

My final goal is to reproduce this jQuery:

```
$(iframe).find('select').filter(':visible').eq(1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **$ on jQuery** and **$ on puppeteer** has no relation. You need to inject jQuery and evaluate script on the page.

To inject jQuery from the cdn,

```
await page.addScriptTag({url: 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js'});
```

To inject a local jQuery,

```
await page.addScriptTag({path: require.resolve('jquery')});
```

And then your the code normally with `page.evaluate`,

```
await page.evaluate(()=>{
  // get the body inside iframe
  const iframe = $("YourSelector").contents().find("body");

  // run your code
  $(iframe).find('input[type=text]').filter(':visible:first').val("abc");
})
```